# Not able to access Eclipse neon after installing it

Tags: eclipse

Today I installed Eclipse Neon on my machine but once i closed the window, I can't find where it is. I checked in the installed softwares also but there also it is not showing. Please help as I need to resume my coding classes.

Comment: What were the steps you used to install it?

Answer (score 0):

The current repository version of Eclipse is 3.8 (Juno).  Since you mentioned you have Neon (the latest release (officially available at http://www.eclipse.org), the package doesn't require an install.  It can be run from the directory where you unpacked it.

You can run this command to locate the the folder:

```
$ locate -r "neon.*/eclipse$"
```

The results will be something similar to:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse-jee-neon-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse
```

I highlighted in bold the part that you will most likely see.  In my case I have moved my root eclipse directory to the folder `/opt` to make it available to other users who logs into the system, instead of my personal space.  You'll most likely see yours in an area such as:

```
/home/username/Downloads//opt/eclipse/eclipse-jee-neon-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse
```

I inferred the latter because your message said you can't find it.  By default files are downloaded to the `~/Downloads` folder.  Opening a package without specifying a folder will create a folder off the `Downloads` directory.

To run it, just go to the folder with the `eclipse` files and run:

```
$ ./eclipse
```

Unless you specifically installed the `jdk` package it'll give the appropriate error indicating.

YOu can correct this by installing the `jdk` package from the repository with:

```
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
```

For convenience you might consider moving the root directory of the package (`eclipse-jee-neon-M5-linux-gtk-x86_64`) to a convenient location and link a path to the `eclipse` execute file.  You can do this with:

```
$ ln -s [path of directory]/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

This way you could run eclipse from the terminal commanline from anywhere just by typing (without a path):

```
$ eclipse
```